# The value of $\iint_{S} x\:dS$

Tags: polar-coordinates, multiple-integral, surface-integrals, parametrization

Let $S$ be the surface defined as: $$\Phi(u, v)=(u+v, u-v, u v)$$
Find the value of $$\iint_{S}x\:dS$$ for all points on $S$ over $R:x^2+y^2\leq 1$

My try:
The surface is $x=u+v, y=u-v, z=uv$
Eliminating $u,v$ we get:
$$4z=x^2-y^2$$

Also we have:

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{2} \quad \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{-y}{2}$

So we have $$d S=\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{x^{2}}{4}+\frac{y^{2}}{4}}\right) d x d y$$

So $$\iint_{S}x\:dS=\iint_{R}x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{x^{2}}{4}+\frac{y^{2}}{4}}\right)dxdy$$

Now by polar coordinates we get
$$\iint_{S}x\:dS=\int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi} \int_{r=0}^{1}(r \cos \theta) \sqrt{1+\frac{r^{2}}{4}}\: r d r d \theta=0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct but as you are evaluating over $(0, 2\pi)$, it would be zero, due to symmetry about x-plane and $x$ being odd function.